# 1.7.1 Popup delay on marker bindpopup (delay on SAFARI & 1.7.1 only)

Tags: leaflet

i'm using Leaflet 1.7.1 (was on 1.6.0) (thanks to the Leaflet team for this so powerfull tool !!!)

My Safari (Old MB Pro) is 13.1.2 (13609.3.5.1.5).

I noticed a delay when clicking on Markers.
If i just click, no popup is displayed.
I have to have a long click to have my popup displayed.
By "clicking", i mean : i have to stay click on, wait for some s, and release the click.
I thought i may have something to do with some Mac Os delay/ some bug in my code, even if it was working well with 1.6.0 Leaflet.

So i test in different ways :

- It's working well on Windows (Chrome, Firefox and IE)
- It is not working on the tutorials example from [leaflet website](http:////https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) (which is in 1.7.1 too) : same delay pb from my MBpro.
- **It is working in 1.6.0** on SAFARI

So , my question, if not already asked (sorry if it was even if i did not find any answer), is :

Is there any possible bug in 1.7.1 according to this delay on bindPopup, or should i have changed something between 1.6 and 1.7 ?

(I'm using markersLayer.addLayer(marker) in a loop from a Json object coming from a simple JS XHR request)
At this time i went back to 1.6.0 to make it work.

```
echo "function loadMarkers(e) {   ";
echo " var bounds = mymap.getBounds();";
echo " var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(); ";
echo " var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(); ";
echo "      markersLayer.clearLayers();                          ";
echo "      bounds = northEast.lat + ',' + northEast.lng + ',' + southWest.lat + ',' + southWest.lng; ";

echo "      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); ";
echo "      xmlhttp.responseType = 'text'; ";
echo "      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {   ";
echo "        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { ";
echo "              var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);                    ";
echo "                   for (var data in obj){                                         ";
echo "                          var marker = new L.marker([obj[data][1], obj[data][2]], {icon: conectIcon}).addTo(mymap)        ";
echo "                                         .bindPopup(obj[data][0]);            ";
echo "                           markersLayer.addLayer(marker);                                 ";
echo "                   }                                                              ";
echo "                   mymap.addLayer(markersLayer);                                  ";
echo "        } ";
echo "      };  ";
echo "      xmlhttp.open(\"GET\", \"xx.php?q=\" + bounds , true);   ";
echo "      xmlhttp.send(); ";
echo "}                      ";

echo " loadMarkers();";

/*
 * EVENTS SUR LA CARTE
 */
echo " mymap.on('drag', function(e) {     ";
echo "         markersLayer.clearLayers();  ";
echo " });                              ";
echo " mymap.on('dragend', function(e) {  ";
echo "             loadMarkers();       ";
echo "     });                          ";
echo "  mymap.on('zoomend', function(e) {        ";
echo "      var currentZoom = mymap.getZoom();    ";
echo "             loadMarkers();               ";
echo "  });                                     ";
```

Comment: forget to add : it's working well for Circles and others polygons popup...

Comment: This is an open issue about leaflet 1.7.1, see [#7331](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7331) and [#7255](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255)